# How to convert php array to javascript's varname.arrkey form?

Tags: javascript, php

I make an ajax call to a php file has the following code

```
$arr = array('oldid' => 18258, 'newid' => 98765);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

then in JS ..

```
$.get("/admin/getdata.php", {
    "otherdata": $("#mydata").val()
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);       // prints {"oldid":"18258","newid":"98765"}
    console.log(data.oldid); // prints undefined
    console.log(data.newid); // prints undefined
});
```

is json_encode not right for when I want to access keys in js like `data.oldid`??

Comment: Set `Content-Type: application/json` for response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP is right but you need to tell the JS that you're expecting JSON. This can be done like this

```
$.getJSON("/admin/getdata.php", {
    "otherdata": $("#mydata").val()
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data.oldid);
});
```

or like this

```
$.get("/admin/getdata.php", {
    "otherdata": $("#mydata").val()
}).done(function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data.oldid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSON.parse in JQuery to process the data which is json encoded in PHP.

```
$.get("/admin/getdata.php", {
    "otherdata": $("#mydata").val()
}).done(function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.oldid);
    console.log(data.newid);
});
```